# Require dynamic fields on form

Tags: php, dynamic, checkbox

Quick question.

I have a form that contains both dynamic checkboxes and textboxes which are paired. When I submit the form and print_r out the $_POST info, this is what I get.

```
    Array
(
    [chkname_156] => chkname_156
    [txtID_156] => 
    [chkname_157] => chkname_157
    [txtID_157] => 
    [doChooseAppSvc] => doChooseAppSvc
)
```

As you can see above, the checkboxes have been checked, but the txtID(s) are empty. What I'm trying to acomplish is this. If the checkboxes are present, which means they've been checked, but the textboxes are empty, I need to alert the user. Since each is dynamic, the numbers after the underscore change, but the beginning of the name stays the same.

I've gotten, I think, half way to a solution by doing the following. I am using preg_grep to create an array of checkboxes that have been checked. Here is that code.

```
$pm = preg_grep("/^chkname.*/", $p);
```

Now, I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using arrays in your form.
It may make it easier to compare values.

For example:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="chkname[<?=$id?>]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="txtID[<?=$id?>]" value="" />
```

Then, for each iteration, you can check:

```php
if (isset($posted['chkname'][$id]) && $posted['txtID'][$id]=='') {
   // alert the user
}
```

### Edit:

Here's an example of a loop to check the inputs:

```
// loop through all text inputs
foreach ($posted['txtID'] as $id => $txtID_value) {

  // for each text input, validate against checkbox with the same $id
  if (isset($posted['chkname'][$id]) && $txtID_value!='') {

    // output an error message
    echo "<p>You checked box #$id but didn't fill in text input #$id.</p>";

  }

}
```

Comment: After the post, where are you getting the $id from? When I check one box and post it, I get the following array.Array
(
    [chkname] => Array
        (
            [156] => chkname156
        )

    [txtID] => Array
        (
            [156] => 1234
            [157] => 
        )

)

Comment: In my example, the `$id` is the index of a particular input set. For example, if you want to check the text/checkbox inputs numbered 156, then `$id=156`. (I imagine you'd loop through the inputs to check them.) Given your array output and my code example, the user would be not be alerted at all because `chkname[156]` is checked and `txtID[156]` is not blank, and `chkname[157]` is not checked but `txtID[157]` is blank. So neither one satisfies my `if` statement and the form is complete/valid.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm more confused now than I was when I first started. I'm trying to figure out how I access each array item when they are dynamic. How do I know what $id is in $posted['chkname'][$id]?

Comment: Yikes, sorry to hear that. I edited my answer with an example validation loop. I hope it helps to clarify and I'm not just leading you down a rabbit hole...